# How can I stop cells from being entered when a datagridview row is selected by a row header click?

Tags: c#, datagridview

Whenever a user clicks the row header, which selects the whole row (and highlights it blue), the cell in the first column is actually entered. That is, if you start typing stuff, the text goes in that cell. I want to prevent this. Would it be possible to have no datagridview cells being entered when one or many rows are selected?

I also need the solution to prevent cells being entered during multiple row selections caused by clicking and dragging on the row headers.

Any ideas on how I could achieve this?

Thanks

Isaac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your DataGridView's ReadOnly property to true or false, depending on whether one or more rows have been selected or if the DGV's 'CellState' has changed.

Add the following two events for your DataGridView:

```
private void dataGridView1_RowStateChanged(object sender, DataGridViewRowStateChangedEventArgs e) {
    if (e.StateChanged == DataGridViewElementStates.Selected) {
        Console.WriteLine("TRUE");
        dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
    }
}

private void dataGridView1_CellStateChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellStateChangedEventArgs e) {
    if (e.StateChanged == DataGridViewElementStates.Selected) {
        Console.WriteLine("false");
        dataGridView1.ReadOnly = false;
    }
}
```

This worked for me in my tests but I wouldn't be surprised if there were hidden 'gotchas.'

Comment: @Jay Riggs-Will the rowheadermouseclick event also fire when a row gets selected during a click and drag?

Comment: @IsaacB - I believe it will as soon as the a row header is clicked.  Can test in about 10 hours.

Comment: its ok, i'll test it later. I'm just worried about rows selected during the mouseover (with the button held down) when multiple rows are being selected

Comment: sorry, i should have been more specific in the earlier comment.

Comment: It doesn't work for when the grid is set to full row select. That's one gotcha I've found so far.

Comment: The problem is that the readonly flag of cells will be removed by `dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;`. Therefore I adjusted your solution. Will post it as an alternative answer.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution may be something like this:

```
    private void dataGrid_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 && dataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected)
            return;
    }
```

Comment: This will only stop executing the `CellEnter` event any further. It won't stop automatically cell editing. I couldn't find any useful way to leave the cell from this event. For example the attempt to cancel edit or changing current cell won't have the desired effects.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of "Jay R" I adjusted the code a bit to not lose readonly flags of cells.

```
private void dataGridView1_RowStateChanged(object sender, DataGridViewRowStateChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.StateChanged == DataGridViewElementStates.Selected)
        e.Row.DataGridView.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditProgrammatically;
}

private void dataGridView1_CellStateChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellStateChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.StateChanged == DataGridViewElementStates.Selected)
        // adjust the edit mode to your "default" edit mode if you have to
        e.Cell.DataGridView.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter;
}
```