# Prevent first cell of DataGridView from being selected when row header clicked

Tags: c#, datagridview

I need to allow the user to select a row by clicking on the row header to allow row deletion, but when the row header is clicked, the first cell gets focus and the text is highlighted, which I need to prevent so the user can't make accidental edits to that first cell.

Here's an example of what's happening:
[image: DGV Row Selected]

As you can see, the first cell has focus and the user can edit that cell, when all that was done was the row header was clicked.

I tried the answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182150/how-can-i-stop-cells-from-being-entered-when-a-datagridview-row-is-selected-by-a), but neither event fired when I clicked a row header. Here's the code that I used for that attempt:

```
private void dgvCategories_RowStateChanged(object sender, DataGridViewRowStateChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.StateChanged == DataGridViewElementStates.Selected)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("true");
        dgvCategories.ReadOnly = true;
    }
}

private void dgvCategories_CellStateChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellStateChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.StateChanged == DataGridViewElementStates.Selected)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("false");
        dgvCategories.ReadOnly = false;
    }
}
```

I also tried experimenting with the various DataGridViewEditMode options, but none of those accomplished what I need.

The DGV SelectionMode is set to RowHeaderSelect.

I still need to be able to grab the hidden "id" field in the row for the delete process. Here's my code for that:

```
private void btnDeleteRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int index = dgvCategories.SelectedRows[0].Index;
    string rowId = dgvCategories[0, index].Value.ToString();

    string deleteString = string.Format("DELETE FROM masterfiles.xref WHERE id = " + rowId);

    conn.Open();
    NpgsqlCommand deleteCmd = new NpgsqlCommand(deleteString, conn);
    deleteCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

That works; I just need to prevent that first cell from automatically getting focus for editing when the row is selected. I still need to allow the user to select individual cells for editing, as well.

Comment: I believe that you have `dgvCategories.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter;`, so setting this to `DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnKeystroke` or `DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnKeystrokeOrF2` will do.

Comment: @JQSOFT - That did the trick, Thanks.

Comment: @JohnG - Nothing was preventing me from doing that, I just mentioned it in case a fix was suggested that might affect/prevent that need.

Answer (score 0):

Try :
1- make the `DataGridView` selection by one row instead of one cell .
2- Disable allowing user to edit the `DataGridView`.
3- Make `DataGridView` ReadOnly .
Do 1 & 2 **all the time** except at editing operation .